# How to change activity of a discord.py bot?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I want to change the bot status from playing to watching. I've tried this but it's still playing status:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

PREFIX = ("$")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description='Hi')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    activity = discord.Game(name="Netflix", type=3)
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)
    print("Bot is ready!")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use the following lines of code, depending on which activity you want to change the bot to:

```
# Setting `Playing ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="a game"))

# Setting `Streaming ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream", url=my_twitch_url))

# Setting `Listening ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="a song"))

# Setting `Watching ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="a movie"))
```

Reference:

[`bot.change_presence`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.change_presence)

Answer (score 26):

Reminder for everyone, **DO NOT** change_presence (or make API calls) in `on_ready` within your Bot or Client.
Discord has a high chance to completely disconnect you during the READY or GUILD_CREATE events (1006 or 1000 close code) and there is nothing you can do to prevent it.

Instead, set the `activity` and `status` kwargs in the constructor of these Classes.

**Playing** ->
`activity = discord.Game(name="!help")`

**Streaming** ->
`activity = discord.Streaming(name="!help", url="twitch_url_here")`

**Listening** ->
`activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="!help")`

**Watching** ->
`activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="!help")`

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", activity=activity, status=discord.Status.idle)
```

Basically: **DO NOT do things in `on_ready`.**

Answer (score 2):

according to [this issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1125) ,game keyword argument in Client.change_presence was renamed to activity so your code should look like

```
activity = discord.Game(name="Just")
await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe try

```
client = commands.Bot (command_prefix = "!" , activity = discord.Game(name="your help command here"))
```

for the playing status

instead of doing it on a command or on ready.

Answer (score 1):

The bot can still be `Playing X` or `Streaming Y` though, just **NOT** custom status

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.change_presence

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name='Fortnite', url='https://www.twitch.tv/UR_TWITCH_GOES_HERE You cant do YT only Twitch.'))
    print("Bot is connected to all of the available servers in the bots mainframe.")
```

for streaming but for the others I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the normal presence then do this :

````
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream", url=my_twitch_url))

await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="a song"))

await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="a movie"))```

#but if you want to make the bot change status every 5 minutes try this :

async def ch_pr():
 await client.wait_until_ready()

 statuses = ["Vodka Or beer? || bb:help",f"listening on {len(client.guilds)} server's","Still need help? do bb:guide for more help!"]

 while not client.is_closed():

   status = random.choice(statuses)

   await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=status))

   await asyncio.sleep(5)

client.loop.create_task(ch_pr())
````

Answer (score -1):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime

from urllib import parse, request
import re

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='prefix here', description="desc here")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="to keep it a secret", url="http://www.twitch.tv/dheeran2010"))
    print('Im Ready')


bot.run('Token here')
```

Comment: please fix formatting, and explain how this answers the question

Answer (score -1):

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def statusloop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"s!help"))
    await sleep(10)
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"{len(client.guilds)} guilds!"))
    await sleep(10)

statusloop.start()
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```py
# Setting `Playing ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="a game"))

# Setting `Streaming ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream", url=my_twitch_url))

# Setting `Listening ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="a song"))

# Setting `Watching ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="a movie"))
```