# How to set discord.py bot status to listening/watching/etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, discord.py

BTW I'm using rewrite version

Here is the code for original version, which seems not to work on rewrite

```
await bot.change_prescence(activity=discord.Game('sample text', type=2))
```

How do I make the bot status listening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change discord.py bot activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126137/how-to-change-discord-py-bot-activity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are all possible Activities

```py
# "Playing"
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Game"))

# "Listening to"
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="Some Song"))

# "Watching"
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="A movie"))

# "Streaming"
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="Drums on!", url="https://www.twitch.tv/the8bitdrummer"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="a song"))
```