# Discord Python Bot: Changing Status

Tags: python, discord, bots

I know, that you can change your bots status with:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=.....(name="....."))
```

But is there an easy way to change your status every like 5 seconds maby by using asyncio?
Thanks for helping :D

Comment: https://youtu.be/K5pkOrjeAIs

Comment: I saw this but it didn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the command of **Cool or Fool - SRS** here the answer that works pretty well:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.loop.create_task(status_task()) # Create loop/task


async def status_task():
    while True:
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("XXX"), status=discord.Status.online)
        await asyncio.sleep(ValueInSeconds) # Changes after x seconds
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("XXX"), status=discord.Status.online)
        await asyncio.sleep(ValueInSeconds)
```

- You can also set `watch`, `listening to` or `streaming` as a status.

For more you can have a look at [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126137/how-to-change-discord-py-bot-activity)