# How do I change my python discord bot's status to streaming?

Tags: python, python-2.7, discord, status

I saw it on someone else's bot so I know it's possible but I don't know how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126137/how-to-change-discord-py-bot-activity

Comment: @IsmailHafeez no for some reason when I paste that command in and save it it shows no errors but if I run my bot it crashes. Without the command it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

In your `on_ready` method or wherever you are placing this status change, inject the following line:

```py
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name='My Stream', url=your_url)
```

`bot` = your client name

For more information, see: [change_presence discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=change_presence#discord.Client.change_presence)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the rewrite, you can add this into your "bot" variable:

```py
bot = Bot(command_prefix="(prefix)", activity=discord.Streaming(name='Stream', url="URL")
```