# How can I change client presence with a command? Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
status = None

@client.command()
async def setstatus(ctx, variable):
  global status
  print("Before", variable)
  status = variable
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))
  await ctx.send(status)
```

Above is the code I currently have and it is not working.

**Error**:
"await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))
TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator"

The goal is to change the bots presence text by using !setstatus.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It explains how to improve your question that makes it easier to read and understand what the exact issue is. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is telling you that `status` is a string and not something that can iterated so a list.

Change this line:
`await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))`

to:

`await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(status))`

Comment: @NDDevelopment if I have solved it can you accept this as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

## Playing A Game

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="status"))
```

## Streaming

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream", url="stream url"))
```

## Listening

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="song"))
```

## Watching

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="a video"))
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [how to change discord.py bot activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126137/how-to-change-discord-py-bot-activity)

```py
# Setting `Playing ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="a game"))

# Setting `Streaming ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream", url=my_twitch_url))

# Setting `Listening ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="a song"))

# Setting `Watching ` status
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="a movie"))
```