# Automatic change of Discord "About me"

Tags: python, http, python-requests, discord, discord.py

**THE PROBLEM**:

In Discord, as you may know, there is an "About me" section.

This section is a description of a profile that you can write yourself.

Bots can have an "About me" section.

What I want to do is to edit this "About me" section automatically in discord.py;
For example, the "About me" section of the bot changes every hour.

**WHAT I TRIED**:

I searched for some answers for a long time but didn't find anything relevant.

I saw that you could modify the "about me" with the Developer portal, but it's not automated.

I saw that some people said "This will be able in discord.py V2" but didn't find it

It may be possible to resolve this problem with HTTP requests but it's only a supposition, I'm not very good at this topic.

**CODE**:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    while 1:
         await change_the_about_me_section(str(random.randint(0,1000))
         time.sleep(3600)
         # change_the_about_me_section isn't a real function
         # I just wanted to show an exemple of what I wanted to do
```

Comment: You do it in the developer portal, no automated way

Comment: There is a chance to use chrome tools to see the request sent to discord for the about me change. The only requirement for discord requests is the auth token which doesn’t change often.

Comment: I could take a crack at doing it with requests later through reverse engineering the web API.I doubt there is an official api option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an answer.

You can fully automate it with Python in a few lines.

With the requests library.

You just have to first include requests with:

```py
import requests
```

Then, do a patch request

```py
requests.patch(url="https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me", headers= {"authorization": token}, json = {"bio": abio} )
# With token your token, and abio a string like "hello"
```

And... that's it :)

(Note: You can also do that with the color of the Account with `accent_color` instead of `bio`, and the banner with `banner` instead of `bio`)

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? Or how do I find out for example what format is expected for `accent_color` and which other elements are supported?

Comment: Also, I'm getting a 401 despite the token being correct. Is this still current?

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this as the application owner/a team member manually in the [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).
Automating this would count as automating your user account (eg. self-boting) wich is against Discords [Terms of Service](https://discord.com/terms) and can get your account banned.

The bot itself has no access to this endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can change your about me using any code. It must be done through the developer portal. On the other hand, you can [change its status through your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126137/how-to-change-discord-py-bot-activity).