# I am trying to make a discord chatbot but I am facing a problem

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pandorabots

I have been trying to make a discord chatbot I finished the code "technically" it should work

Here's my code :

```
import asyncio, aiohttp, discord, re

class FrostCleverbot(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logging In...')
        await self.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='chat with me!'))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot and (not message.server or message.server.me in message.mentions):
            await self.send_typing(message.channel)
            try:
                input = re.sub('<@!?'+self.user.id+'>', '', message.content).strip()
                params = {'botid': 'f6d4afd83e34564d', 'custid': message.author.id, 'input': input or 'Hello'}
                async with http.get('https://www.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk-xml', params=params) as resp:
                    if resp.status == 200:
                        text = await resp.text()
                        text = text[text.find('<that>')+6:text.rfind('</that>')]
                        text = text.replace('&quot;','"').replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;','>').replace('&amp;','&').replace('<br>',' ')
                        await self.send_message(message.channel, text)
                    else:
                        await self.send_message(message.channel, 'Uh oh, I didn\'t quite catch that!')
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await self.send_message(message.channel, 'Uh oh, I think my head is on backwards!')

print('Starting...')
http = aiohttp.ClientSession()
FrostCleverbot().run('token')
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Starting...
d:\New folder\file.py:26: DeprecationWarning: The object should be created within an async function
  http = aiohttp.ClientSession()
Logging In...
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\New folder\fff.py", line 6, in on_ready
    await self.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='chat with me!'))
TypeError: Client.change_presence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'game'
```

Any help would be super appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change discord.py bot activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126137/how-to-change-discord-py-bot-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not familiar with Dicord's API,
but I'm pretty sure it should be activity instead of game

```
await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='chat with me!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

move discord folders out of site-packages.
move both folders from this location:
"C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages

too this location:
"C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib