# Removing 'Playing' Prefix from Discord Bot Status in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.js, discord.py

I'm working on a Discord bot using discord.py and I'm trying to set the bot's status without the default 'Playing', 'Watching', 'Listening to' etc., prefixes that Discord adds. My goal is to have a simple status message like "Ready to help! | B!", but I'm encountering issues in achieving this.

**Current Approach:**

When I set the status using discord.Game, it adds a 'Playing' prefix:

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=current_status))
```

This results in a status like: "Playing Ready to help! | B!", which is not what I want.

**Attempted Solution:**

I tried using discord.Activity with ActivityType.custom, but it led to no status being displayed:

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.custom, name=current_status))
```

**End Goal Visualization:**

> I aim for a status display similar to this bot, which does not show
> any prefix: [Pancake bot no prefix
> status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk48x.png)
>
> However, my current approach results in this: [My
> bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFFkH.png)

**MRE:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import random

async def change_presence():
    statuses = ["Ready to help! | B!", "Here to help! | B!", "Your friendly bot! | B!", "Ready for commands! |B!"]
    while True:
        current_status = random.choice(statuses)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=current_status))  # This adds the 'Playing' prefix
        # await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.custom, name=current_status))  # No status shown
        await asyncio.sleep(7200)

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("B!", "b!", "bot!", "Bot!"), intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is starting...")
    client.loop.create_task(change_presence())
    print("Bot is ready for action!")

client.run("your_token_here")
```

Is there a way in discord.py (or even in JavaScript) to achieve the status without the prefix? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please explain what exactly it is you're trying to achieve.  What is current_status?   If you don't want the status to be displayed, what happens if you replace the ```current_status``` to ```None```?  Please include some sort of minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Is the image your MRE?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please put what you want to do within the actual post instead of a string of comments

Comment: @BlueRobin ah apologies - I'm a bit new to this. I have now refactored my post which should be more streamlined now & deleted past (now redundant) comments.

Comment: Are you talking about the "Playing" before the prefix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change activity of a discord.py bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126137/how-to-change-activity-of-a-discord-py-bot)

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the 'Playing', 'Watching', 'Listening to' prefixes that Discord adds before a status message.

The linked post is not quite it. I was looking for a way to remove the Playing', 'Watching', 'Listening to', not just changing 'playing' to 'watching'.
The question has been solved by another user. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom status using the [`discord.CustomActivity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.CustomActivity) class with [`ActivityType.custom`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ActivityType.custom) e.g.

```py
activity = discord.CustomActivity(name="pancake.gg | p!help")
await client.change_presence(activity=activity)
```

Another way is to use the default [`discord.Activity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Activity) class e.g.

```py
activity = discord.Activity(
   type = discord.ActivityType.custom,
   name = "Custom Status",  # does nothing but is required
   state = "pancake.gg | p!help"
)
await client.change_presence(activity=activity)
```

But the first way is the recommended one.
So Your modified code would be

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import random

async def change_presence():
    statuses = ["Ready to help! | B!", "Here to help! | B!", "Your friendly bot! | B!", "Ready for commands! |B!"]
    while True:
        current_status = random.choice(statuses)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.CustomActivity(name=current_status))  # This doesn't add any suffixes
        # await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.custom, name=current_status))  # No status shown
        await asyncio.sleep(7200)

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("B!", "b!", "bot!", "Bot!"), intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is starting...")
    client.loop.create_task(change_presence())
    print("Bot is ready for action!")

client.run("your_token_here")
```

Edit: Upon further inspection, I saw that you already used this but didn't include the state argument which is the actual text to be shown in the status. The name and state are both required (due to API limitation) even though the name does nothing in this context and the state is the actual text that is used